# Getting Contiguous Shifts

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields:

```
-id (int)
-team_id(int)
-user_id (int)
-date (date)
-start_time(time)
-end_time(time)
```

Running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `shifts` WHERE user_id = 1 order by team_id, date, start_time;
```

Gives me the following result:

```
id   team_id  user_id  date         start_time end_time
1    3        1        2017-11-29   10:00:00   11:00:00
2    3        1        2017-11-29   11:00:00   12:00:00
5    3        1        2017-11-29   12:00:00   13:00:00
6    3        1        2017-11-29   16:00:00   17:00:00
7    3        1        2017-11-29   17:00:00   18:00:00
10   4        1        2017-11-30   17:00:00   18:00:00
8    4        1        2017-11-30   19:00:00   20:00:00
51   5        1        2017-11-30   18:00:00   19:00:00
11   5        1        2017-11-30   19:00:00   20:00:00
```

I am looking for a query that gives me the following result with contiguous start_time - end_time:

```
driver_id team_id date        contiguous_start_time  contiguous_end_time  hours
1         3       2017-11-29  10:00:00               13:00:00             3
1         3       2017-11-29  16:00:00               18:00:00             2
1         4       2017-11-30  17:00:00               18:00:00             1
1         4       2017-11-30  19:00:00               20:00:00             1
1         5       2017-11-30  18:00:00               20:00:00             2
```

Any and all help is appreciated.